# change default user of webserver for special directories

Tags: php, apache, content-management-system, apache2

for example, if i'm using a php script that writes files, or using a cms , the files and folders that are generated are owned by a special user (f.e. `www-data:www-data`)

is it possible to change this default user for special directories?
so that for example all cms systems or php scripts in general use another user and group in the dir `/httpdocs/somedir`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, It's only possible if you run PHP as CGI (rather than Apache module). For instance, FastCGI allows to use suexec:

- http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/81

Answer (score 0):

- What do you want to do with these special directories?
- Who/what will be able to access these directories?
- What kind of special permissions needed?

For example:

If you want to access files via FTP that are uploaded via the administration panel (www-data) you need to adjust permissions on this folder. You can create a special group under your OS like `ftpweb`, add your www-data and FTP-user to this group then change the folders' group to this so both www-data and your FTP-user can access.

**Edit:**

```
groupadd ftpweb
usermod www-data -a -G ftpweb
usermod your_ftp_user -a -G ftpweb
chgrp ftpweb your_special_dir
```

- [groupadd(8) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/groupadd)
- [Howto: Linux Add User To Group](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-add-user-to-group/)

Comment: sounds good. can you give me a short hint how to create a group and assign users to it?

Comment: @choise: Edited. Note: i don't know anything about your current settings please do these modifications carefully. I've also provided some useful links.